# Survey results graph for "How satisfied are developers with their equipment" needs fixed maximum

Tags: bug, survey-2017

The "[How satisfied are developers with their equipment](https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017#work-how-satisfied-are-developers-with-their-equipment)" graph needs to have its maximum set to 5. This was the maximum in the question, but the graph makes it look like all were fully satisfied.

From OP in comments:
It was about that survey listed [graph here](https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017#work-how-satisfied-are-developers-with-their-equipment). I felt this was in a scope of feedback that was specific to the survey.

The request is that the graph in the above link has the horizontal axis go from 0 to 5, which would make the bars only go to ~3.7 along this axis.

Comment: Maybe it is a after effect of seeing that graph.

Comment: My apologies for a poor bug report. I should have provided more context. It was about that survey listed https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017#work-how-satisfied-are-developers-with-their-equipment
I felt this was in a scope of feedback that was specific to the survey. My apologies for assuming.
The request is that the graph in the above link have the horizontal axis go from 0 to 5, which would make the bars only go to ~3.7 along this axis.

Comment: @Brian, As always with Questions, please [edit] pertinent information into the Question. Don't *only* put the information in comments. Having it *also* in comments is fine, but the Question should have complete information.

Comment: Btw @PeterMortensen spelling out contractions has nothing to do with active vs passive language